# How to add a dynamic variable to the key value of a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I am looping through a list and would like to reference the loop index number in the key of a hash.

Example:

```
     unit_type = Hash.new      
      index = 5 
       list.each do |x| 
        unit_type[:loop_[index]] = x 
         index = index + 1 
      end
```

The resulting key hash value should be:

```
             unit_type = {:loop_5 #> "test result"}
```

How can I pass the index number in the key title together with other text as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

i think we can use `to_sym`

```
list.each do |x|
 unit_type["loop_#{index}".to_sym] = x
 index =+ 1
end
```

Comment: `:"loop_#{index}"` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby allows `#{...}` interpolation for [symbol literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbol+Literals). You could also utilize [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html#with_index-method) to inject an index right into the loop:

```
list = %w[a b c]

unit_type = {}
list.each.with_index(5) do |x, i|
  unit_type[:"loop_#{i}"] = x
end

unit_type
#=> {:loop_5=>"a", :loop_6=>"b", :loop_7=>"c"}
```

Alternatively, via [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#to_h-method) which creates a hash based on key-value pairs returned by the block:

```
list = %w[a b c]

unit_type = list.each.with_index(5).to_h { |x, i| [:"loop_#{i}", x] }
#=> {:loop_5=>"a", :loop_6=>"b", :loop_7=>"c"}
```